# Laravel 5.0 show logged in guests and registered users

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, laravel

I am attempting to add a function to my site that shows the number of logged in guests and registered users(displaying the names of the registered users as well but I can figure out that part).  Presently, I have read that I need to change the /config/Session.php file 'driver' to use `database` instead of `file` (`'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),`).  I found an article that uses Sentry to accomplish this (http://laravel.io/forum/03-03-2014-sentry-3-users-online), however, I would prefer to do this without requiring third party files.  I have, nonetheless, used his information as a starting point for now utilizing a model for the session.

As for the issues, first off, I am unable to actually get the session to start saving in my database 'sessions' table even after modifying Session.php, creating the table and migrating it.  It is still saving in files in /storage/framework/session/ (I can still log in and display the session information using `Session::all()`).

```
mysql> select * from sessions;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Second issue, I don't know how I am to create the session if one does not already exist given in his file, there is no way to create (if someone just opens up the site and are thus, a guest) nor unregister a user when they log out (remove their logged-in status as well as their user_id so they are seen as guest).

Here is my current OnlineUser.php file:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
// use Sentry;
use Session;
use Auth;

class OnlineUser extends Model {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public $table = 'sessions';

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * Returns all the guest users.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeGuests($query)
    {
        return $query->whereNull('user_id');
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the registered users.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeRegistered($query)
    {
        return $query->whereNotNull('user_id')->with('user');
    }

    /**
     * Updates the session of the current user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeUpdateCurrent($query)
    {
        return $query->where('id', Session::getId())->update(array(
            'user_id' => !empty(Auth::user()) ? Auth::user()->id : null
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the user that belongs to this entry.
     *
     * @return \Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\EloquentUser
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\User');
        //return $this->belongsTo('Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\EloquentUser'); # Sentry 3
        // return $this->belongsTo('Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User'); # Sentry 2
    }

}
```

If anyone has any information to assist me in solving these problems, I would be much obliged.  If you need more information, let me know and I will respond when I am able to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the first issue where Laravel still save the session in /storage/framework/session/

if you updated your session.php file as follows:

> env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database')

make sure you also update your .env file

> SESSION_DRIVER=database

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; I have been working on other parts since.  That got the database working... Now I just need to figure out how to get a user's id from either the session OR save the user's id to the session table which it doesn't seem to want to do.